# Crystal Reports: Hour based selection criteria won't cross midnight

Tags: datetime, crystal-reports, selection, criteria

I've got a formula I've used dozens of times with consistent success that suddenly isn't working and I'm baffled.

I'm trying to generate data for a 24 hour period.  I've done this several times in the past, and it's always worked with the following formula:

{datetime} in dateadd("h",-24,currentdatetime) to currentdatetime

For reasons I can't figure out, it's now decided to not back prior to midnight.  Say I'm running this report at 8a, I'm only getting records from 12a - 8a, despite the 24 hour parameter.

Crystal Version: 14.2.8.3594 (can't get any more current as DB requires 32-bit)

I've confirmed the source field is a datetime.  I've also confirmed that my server time is the same as my local time. I've tried that single line of code.  I've also tried making separate start and end formulas, but alas no difference.  If I bump that parameter up to -48 hours it, I guess somewhat suspected, goes back to Midnight the day prior, but again won't cross midnight.